# Background image over text disappearing in HTML email when saving to Google drive

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I am trying to save an email from my Gmail to the Google drive (Print -> choose Save to Google Drive). However, I realised whenever there it is a background image with text over it, the image is lost! I have tested this with other emails as well and the same issue happened.

For example, in Gmail it looks like:
[image]

When saving to Google Drive:
[image]

This basically is the behaviour when I fw the email as well. What can I do to fw or save this email properly?

Answer (score 0):

[Google seems to be aware of the issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/RHzvFYwjuZQ), and were 'working to fix it' back in the day when this post was made.

There are a few fixes floating around that work occasionally.  Here are the highlights:

- Click the control and p buttons and print from that dialog if the
  email fits on one page (or open in a new window)
- Download the page HTML and use that dialog
- Print screen (awful hack, but foolproof)